# Propel getting results from joining multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I have multiple tables linked in propel, but can't seem to access certain data when I join.

```
QuestionQuery::create()
    ->select(Array("Run.title", "Question.text"))
    ->join("Question.Answer")
    ->joinWith("Answer.Run")
    ->withColumn("Run.title", "Question.text");
```

I realize I probably am not supposed to need all of those selects and withs together, but even with all of them, I .find() and don't get the title or any Run data at all.  All I get is Question data.  In the sql statement from .toString() I see that I am selecting stuff from the Run table (in fact, it selects everything, even though all I need is the title).

Answer has a foreign key to Question and also a foreign key to Run.

What gives?

Comment: Mind to post your Question|Run|Answer schema.xml|yml?

Comment: You have a wrong usage of `withColumn` method: the first parameter is the clause and the second is the alias for that clause. Here you select `Run.title` column and alias the result to `Question.text`.